# AT+ROLE = 1 is not working in hc-06

Tags: bluetooth, at-commands

I'm try to study master - slave by using aduino with hc-06.
I checked AT command is working ( ex) AT -> "ok" , AT+NAME ... )

I tried to use command AT+ROLE = 1 but it is not working. (Every device is not working...)
Please help...

this is my code
I used command in seri

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int bttx = 2;
const int btrx = 3;

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(bttx, btrx);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("START");
 
}

void loop(){
  if (BTSerial.available())
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On HC06 you cannot switch between master and slave mode, it is fixed in firmware. The original modules came in two flavors HC06-S and HC06-M, but currently there are so many different firmware clones in the wild, that it is hard to say, what the capabilities of your module are. Most of them have fixed master mode.

You need either HC05 modules to do this or you install the firmware of HC05 in your modules, because the hardware is the same. This is a lot of work and unless you have a hundred modules it is probably not worth the effort.

Currently the clones with only one small BEKEN chip and blue colored PCB are the best implementation I could find.